# How can I revert an unmanaged plugin from an org

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using dynamics crm 8.1.

I've connected to an org that has a plugin that is traditionally deployed to that org as part of a managed solution.   I overwrote a plugin using the plugin registration tool.  This plugin now is presumably an unmanaged asset that I expect will always sit on top of the managed version that is deployed as part of the solution.

How can I erase the unmanaged version of the plugin from the org so that future upgrades of the managed solution will apply to that org?   I assume this involves a crm script of some kind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some database reverse engineering, I've come up with an answer for my own question.   This process worked for me, but I cannot guarantee that it will work for everyone.

When a plugin assembly is replaced using plugin registration tool, it will do three things.

1) The OverwriteTime column of the PluginAssemblyBase record for that plugin will be modified.
2) A new PluginAssemblyBase record will be added for the plugin's assembly that you just added.
3) The record in TopSolutionId column for the DependencyNodeBase record will be modified for the plugin.

The reversal process for this was performed using the following SQL Query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE dbo.PluginAssemblyBase 
        WHERE PluginAssemblyIdUnique <> @originalPluginAssemblyIdUnique and Name = @assemblyName and OverwriteTime = 0

        UPDATE dbo.PluginAssemblyBase SET
            OverwriteTime='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        WHERE PluginAssemblyIdUnique = @originalPluginAssemblyIdUnique

        UPDATE dbo.DependencyNodeBase SET
            TopSolutionId = @ManagedSolutionId
        WHERE Objectid = @pluginAssemblyId
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

That script can be used by others, but in addition to setting the variables, you may want to add some validation in there so that it isn't used under the wrong scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The unmanaged version of a plugin assembly will not "sit on top" of the managed version. It just replaces the managed version. In other words, this solution component behaves different compared to e.g. entity forms and labels.

Import the managed solution again or upgrade the managed solution if that's more convenient. This will convert your unmanaged plugin into a managed version automatically.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would that look from the perspective of the PluginAssembly table?    Does it remove both the managed and unmanaged rows when I do a managed solution import?   Or does the act of uploading the plugin using the PluginRegistrationTool only keep one instance of that assembly name in the table?

Comment: Unmanaged version will never sit on top of any Managed component irrespective of type. Every unmanaged component will merge in to default solution. It cannot be rolled back.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I'm confident that your comment is false.  Unmanaged components in the default solution are meant to be applied in such a way that the managed components don't get applied to the UX if there are also published unmanaged versions of those components.   This is what I've been trained from multiple sources including pluralsight, personal experience, etc.... What source material are you working from?  It would be interesting to review.

Comment: @Jason: there will be only one row in table PluginAssemblyBase for an assembly with a unique name + major version + minor version. The system handles the management of this table and I have never had issues with it.

Comment: @Jason are you saying that removing unmanaged solution will rollback to the earlier managed version? then your question should never come here. :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth No. For the scope of this conversation, I don't think unmanaged solutions need to be entertained. 

Managed components, which are frequently deployed with managed solutions will generally not be part of the UX if there is an UNMANAGED version of the same component in that org.   Your comment from an hour ago suggests that managed components will not take a backseat to unmanaged components, and that's where I think our understanding conflicts.  AFAIK, unmanaged components (which by coincidence are sometimes part of the default solution) should take precedence over managed ones.

Comment: ok to be clear. "SIT ON TOP" or "BACKSEAT" in the sense - the original managed item (form or plugin) cannot come back to the front row (UX) again when the unmanaged solution (not the item) is removed/deleted..

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I think you're mistaken about this.   I just applied a managed solution that contains a plugin to a target org, then updated a modified plugin assembly using Plugin Registration Tool, then Re-imported the managed solution and the plugin still had the behavior of the plugin that I directly updated.   this would suggest that the change that I made with Plugin registration tool is taking precedence over the plugin imported with the managed solution even though the Managed solution was applied last.